How do I correctly import jsPDF and use it for a button's onclick?
I am trying to use jsPDF to make a pdf in a webpage, but my code doesn't seem to be working. Most of the code is copied from the jsPDF documentation, though, so I'm not sure where the issue is, or how to make it simpler to find the bug.


<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/1.4.1/jspdf.debug.js"></script>
<script>
function makepdf() {
  const doc = new jsPDF();
  document.getElementById('name').innerHTML = 'making pdf 1';
  doc.text("Hello world!", 10, 10);
  document.getElementById('makepdf').innerHTML = 'making pdf 2';
  doc.save("a4.pdf");
}
</script>
<p></p>
<button id = 'makepdf' onclick = "makepdf();">Make PDF</button>



None of the innerHTML changes I have in here to are triggering, so I think it's not even getting to those, let alone creating the PDF. Most of the code is copied from the jsPDF documentation. What am I doing incorrectly? Thank you!

This is a good time to familiarize yourself with your browser's development tools.  In particular the development console, which is reporting an error.  You're trying to set a property on an element that doesn't exist.

there are some minor bugs in your makepdf function, there is no dom element with id name. There is issue with using the jsPDF. You can try with latest version <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/2.5.1/jspdf.umd.min.js"></script> . You can check this jsfiddle example
